# Embedded Jetty 10 With Vaadin 14

Tags: jetty, vaadin

I am moving a Vaadin 8 application with an embedded Jetty server to Vaadin 14. In my new version I am compiling from and to Java 11. I have the application working with Vaadin 14 and Jetty 9 but I would like to upgrade to Jetty 10.   I have tried a lot of combinations of Jetty 10 dependencies and versions but haven't be enable to make it work. Can this be done? If so, what do I need in my POM?

I created a trivial application with the same Jetty server setup as my real app.  Like my real app, it compiles and runs as expected.
When I change the version of jetty from:

```
<jetty.version>9.4.44.v20210927</jetty.version>
```

to:

```
<jetty.version>10.0.9</jetty.version>
```

three dependencies break.  I have tried to correct them as follows:
(1) Removed -

```
<!--        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-continuation</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    </dependency>
-->
```

(2) Switched to a replacement -

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax-websocket-serverimpl</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </dependency>
-->
```

(3) Switched to a replacement -

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
<!--        <artifactId>websocket-server</artifactId> -->
            <artifactId>websocket-jetty-server</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

I changed this import in my Java source:

```
//import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356.server.deploy.WebSocketServerContainerInitializer;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.config.JettyWebSocketServletContainerInitializer;
```

and fiddled with the code until it would compile.  When I run it I get:

```
main] WARN org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.BaseHolder - Unable to load class org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.listener.ELContextCleaner
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.listener.ELContextCleaner
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:531)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.BaseHolder.doStart(BaseHolder.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ListenerHolder.doStart(ListenerHolder.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1304)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:895)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:306)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:532)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:414)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
    at uk.co.scapps.example.Application.run(Application.java:193)
    at uk.co.scapps.example.Application.main(Application.java:124)
[main] WARN org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext - Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@58be6e8{/,[file:///home/dan/Downloads/todo14/my-todo/target/classes/META-INF/resources/, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/flow-data/2.6.2/flow-data-2.6.2.jar!/META-INF/resources, file:///home/dan/Downloads/todo14/my-todo/target/classes/META-INF/resources/, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/org/webjars/bowergithub/vaadin/vaadin-radio-button/1.5.1/vaadin-radio-button-1.5.1.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/vaadin-iron-list-flow/14.6.2/vaadin-iron-list-flow-14.6.2.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/org/webjars/bowergithub/vaadin/vaadin-checkbox/2.5.0/vaadin-checkbox-2.5.0.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/webjar/vaadin-cookie-consent/1.2.0/vaadin-cookie-consent-1.2.0.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/org/webjars/bowergithub/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/1.2.6/webcomponentsjs-1.2.6.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/org/webjars/bowergithub/vaadin/vaadin-themable-mixin/1.6.2/vaadin-themable-mixin-1.6.2.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/vaadin-date-picker-flow/14.6.2/vaadin-date-picker-flow-14.6.2.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/org/webjars/bowergithub/vaadin/vaadin-progress-bar/1.3.0/vaadin-progress-bar-1.3.0.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/org/webjars/bowergithub/vaadin/vaadin-usage-statistics/2.1.0/vaadin-usage-statistics-2.1.0.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/vaadin-time-picker-flow/14.6.2/vaadin-time-picker-flow-14.6.2.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/flow-dnd/2.6.2/flow-dnd-2.6.2.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/org/webjars/bowergithub/insites/cookieconsent/3.1.0/cookieconsent-3.1.0.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/org/webjars/bowergithub/polymerelements/iron-meta/2.1.1/iron-meta-2.1.1.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/org/webjars/bowergithub/vaadin/vaadin-app-layout/2.2.0/vaadin-app-layout-2.2.0.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/org/webjars/bowergithub/vaadin/vaadin-icons/4.3.2/vaadin-icons-4.3.2.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/org/webjars/bowergithub/vaadin/vaadin-accordion/1.2.0/vaadin-accordion-1.2.0.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/org/webjars/bowergithub/polymer/polymer/2.7.0/polymer-2.7.0.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/org/webjars/bowergithub/polymerelements/iron-media-query/2.1.0/iron-media-query-2.1.0.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/vaadin-select-flow/14.6.2/vaadin-select-flow-14.6.2.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/org/webjars/bowergithub/polymerelements/iron-icon/2.1.0/iron-icon-2.1.0.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/org/webjars/bowergithub/vaadin/vaadin-custom-field/1.3.0/vaadin-custom-field-1.3.0.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/org/webjars/bowergithub/polymerelements/iron-a11y-announcer/2.1.0/iron-a11y-announcer-2.1.0.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/org/webjars/bowergithub/polymerelements/iron-fit-behavior/2.2.1/iron-fit-behavior-2.2.1.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/org/webjars/bowergithub/vaadin/vaadin-time-picker/2.4.0/vaadin-time-picker-2.4.0.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/org/webjars/bowergithub/vaadin/vaadin-development-mode-detector/2.0.4/vaadin-development-mode-detector-2.0.4.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/org/webjars/bowergithub/webcomponents/shadycss/1.8.0/shadycss-1.8.0.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/flow-server/2.6.2/flow-server-2.6.2.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/org/webjars/bowergithub/polymerelements/iron-resizable-behavior/2.1.1/iron-resizable-behavior-2.1.1.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/org/webjars/bowergithub/vaadin/vaadin-list-box/1.4.0/vaadin-list-box-1.4.0.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/vaadin-combo-box-flow/14.6.2/vaadin-combo-box-flow-14.6.2.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/org/webjars/bowergithub/vaadin/vaadin-list-mixin/2.5.1/vaadin-list-mixin-2.5.1.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/org/webjars/bowergithub/vaadin/vaadin-lumo-styles/1.6.1/vaadin-lumo-styles-1.6.1.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/org/webjars/bowergithub/vaadin/vaadin-button/2.4.0/vaadin-button-2.4.0.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/webjar/vaadin-confirm-dialog/1.3.0/vaadin-confirm-dialog-1.3.0.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/webjar/vaadin-rich-text-editor/1.3.0/vaadin-rich-text-editor-1.3.0.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/org/webjars/bowergithub/vaadin/vaadin-material-styles/1.3.2/vaadin-material-styles-1.3.2.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/org/webjars/bowergithub/vaadin/vaadin-login/1.2.0/vaadin-login-1.2.0.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/vaadin-grid-flow/14.6.2/vaadin-grid-flow-14.6.2.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/vaadin-text-field-flow/14.6.2/vaadin-text-field-flow-14.6.2.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/vaadin-grid-pro-flow/14.6.2/vaadin-grid-pro-flow-14.6.2.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/flow-push/2.6.2/flow-push-2.6.2.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/org/webjars/bowergithub/vaadin/vaadin-form-layout/2.3.0/vaadin-form-layout-2.3.0.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/org/webjars/bowergithub/vaadin/vaadin-select/2.4.0/vaadin-select-2.4.0.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/webjar/vaadin-charts/6.3.1/vaadin-charts-6.3.1.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/org/webjars/bowergithub/vaadin/vaadin-context-menu/4.5.0/vaadin-context-menu-4.5.0.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/org/webjars/bowergithub/vaadin/vaadin-date-time-picker/1.4.0/vaadin-date-time-picker-1.4.0.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/org/webjars/bowergithub/vaadin/vaadin-details/1.2.0/vaadin-details-1.2.0.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/org/webjars/bowergithub/polymerelements/iron-list/2.0.20/iron-list-2.0.20.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/org/webjars/bowergithub/vaadin/vaadin-dialog/2.5.2/vaadin-dialog-2.5.2.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/org/webjars/bowergithub/vaadin/vaadin-date-picker/4.4.1/vaadin-date-picker-4.4.1.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/org/webjars/bowergithub/vaadin/license-checker/2.1.2/license-checker-2.1.2.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/org/webjars/bowergithub/polymerelements/iron-scroll-target-behavior/2.1.1/iron-scroll-target-behavior-2.1.1.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/org/webjars/bowergithub/polymerelements/iron-overlay-behavior/2.3.4/iron-overlay-behavior-2.3.4.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/org/webjars/bowergithub/polymerelements/iron-flex-layout/2.0.3/iron-flex-layout-2.0.3.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/org/webjars/bowergithub/vaadin/vaadin-overlay/3.5.1/vaadin-overlay-3.5.1.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/webjar/vaadin-crud/1.3.0/vaadin-crud-1.3.0.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/webjar/vaadin-grid-pro/2.3.0/vaadin-grid-pro-2.3.0.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/org/webjars/npm/vaadin__vaadin-mobile-drag-drop/1.0.0/vaadin__vaadin-mobile-drag-drop-1.0.0.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/org/webjars/bowergithub/vaadin/vaadin-ordered-layout/1.4.0/vaadin-ordered-layout-1.4.0.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/org/webjars/bowergithub/vaadin/vaadin-upload/4.4.1/vaadin-upload-4.4.1.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/org/webjars/bowergithub/vaadin/vaadin-menu-bar/1.2.2/vaadin-menu-bar-1.2.2.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/org/webjars/bowergithub/vaadin/vaadin-split-layout/4.3.0/vaadin-split-layout-4.3.0.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/org/webjars/bowergithub/vaadin/vaadin-item/2.3.0/vaadin-item-2.3.0.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/vaadin-menu-bar-flow/14.6.2/vaadin-menu-bar-flow-14.6.2.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/org/webjars/bowergithub/vaadin/vaadin-control-state-mixin/2.2.4/vaadin-control-state-mixin-2.2.4.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/org/webjars/bowergithub/vaadin/vaadin-element-mixin/2.4.2/vaadin-element-mixin-2.4.2.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/org/webjars/bowergithub/vaadin/vaadin-combo-box/5.4.7/vaadin-combo-box-5.4.7.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/webjar/vaadin-board/2.2.0/vaadin-board-2.2.0.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/org/webjars/bowergithub/polymerelements/iron-iconset-svg/2.2.1/iron-iconset-svg-2.2.1.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/org/webjars/bowergithub/vaadin/vaadin-notification/1.6.1/vaadin-notification-1.6.1.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/org/webjars/bowergithub/vaadin/vaadin-grid/5.7.13/vaadin-grid-5.7.13.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/org/webjars/bowergithub/polymerelements/iron-a11y-keys-behavior/2.1.1/iron-a11y-keys-behavior-2.1.1.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/vaadin-context-menu-flow/14.6.2/vaadin-context-menu-flow-14.6.2.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/org/webjars/bowergithub/vaadin/vaadin-text-field/2.8.4/vaadin-text-field-2.8.4.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/org/webjars/bowergithub/vaadin/vaadin-tabs/3.2.0/vaadin-tabs-3.2.0.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/flow-client/2.6.2/flow-client-2.6.2.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/org/webjars/npm/mobile-drag-drop/2.3.0-rc.1/mobile-drag-drop-2.3.0-rc.1.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/dan/.m2/repository/org/webjars/bowergithub/vaadin/vaadin-avatar/1.0.4/vaadin-avatar-1.0.4.jar!/META-INF/resources],UNAVAILABLE}
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Class loading error for holder org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.listener.ELContextCleaner@7e0aadd0{src=DESCRIPTOR:jar:file:/home/dan/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-webapp/10.0.9/jetty-webapp-10.0.9.jar!/org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/webdefault.xml}
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.BaseHolder.doStart(BaseHolder.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ListenerHolder.doStart(ListenerHolder.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1304)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:895)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:306)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:532)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:414)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
    at uk.co.scapps.example.Application.run(Application.java:193)
    at uk.co.scapps.example.Application.main(Application.java:124)
```

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: https://github.com/mvysny/vaadin14-embedded-jetty-gradle    , if you are working with maven then try this https://github.com/mvysny/vaadin14-embedded-jetty